# Sukkah walls...lavod?

Tags: sukkah

I have a new pergola that is at a slant from the house and the floor has an incline. The result of is a gap above the walls between the frame and the schach. How much a gap is permitted between the top of the wall and the actual schach in cm's?

Many Thanks

YC

Comment: A picture would help if the question is about a specific formation. If the question is "how much horizontal air may exist between _s'chach_ and the wall of a _suka_?" it should probably read more like that.

Comment: Is the schach directly above the walls or is it to the side? If it is to the side is it only to the side or is it both higher than the end of the walls and to the side?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the question...how much air is permissible between the top of the wall to the schach? The walls are directly under the schah and the beams from the pergola...

Answer (score 2):

> How much a gap is permitted between the top of the wall and the actual schach in cm's

Once you have 10 tefachim (80 cm) of solid wall, there's no limit how far the wall can be from the Schach (up to 20 Amot - 18 meters) on condition that the edge of the Schach is above the wall. (שולחן ערוך · אורח חיים · סימן תרל)

- Actually the wall needn't be "solid" - it must start within 3 Tefachim (24 cm) of the floor.